# Why is the code not compiling?

Tags: tikz-cd, compilation-error

Why the following code is not compiling?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
 \begin{center} 
  \begin{tikzcd}
\Sigma M \arrow[r, "\text{Pinch}"] \arrow[d] & \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \arrow[d, "(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)"] \\
* \arrow[r, "f'"']   \\
& N 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a wrong `\\`, but the main problem is

```
\arrow[d, "(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)"]
```

where the commas confuse the parser. Use braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\Sigma M \arrow[r, "\mathrm{Pinch}"] \arrow[d] &[0.5em] 
\Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \arrow[d, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}"] \\
* \arrow[r, "f'"'] & N 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Better `\mathrm` than `\text`, in this case.